# Google Health -  Making a doctor profile and retrieve profiles - JAVA

Tags: java

I made an application in java who logs in my health google account, take the CCR 
document and processes it. 
Now I need to make and application that logs into a doctor profile ( a 
profile that I will made ) and retrieves CCR document of his patients. 
Can you help me with some indication, how can I do that? 
Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by reading the [Google Health API](http://code.google.com/apis/health/)

In the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/health/docs/2.0/developers_guide.html) you can find [examples](http://code.google.com/apis/health/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html) of authentication and retrieval of CCR in Java

Comment: I succed to authenticate and to retrive ccr document that contains my profile. Now I want to authenticate in a doctor's profile and to retrive the ccr documents from his patients